# Error Magento 2 when edit product in adminpanel

Tags: mysql, magento2

Magento version 2.2.5, everything was good, then probably I did something (maybe switching to production mode or some url_rewrite manipulations)
 but now this strange error, I've never met before. Maybe someone get same error and could help? Nothing like clean cache, reindex, upgrade etc doesn't help..

When I try to edit a product an error message appears:

```
{"0":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty, query was: ","1":"#0 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Statement\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)\n#1 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Statement.php(303): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Statement\\Pdo\\Mysql->_execute(Array)\n#2 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)\n#3 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('', Array)\n#4 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(533): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('', Array)\n#5 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php(596): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_query('', Array)\n#6 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php(737): Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->query('', Array)\n#7 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Attribute\/ScopeOverriddenValue.php(153): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('')\n#8 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Attribute\/ScopeOverriddenValue.php(104): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Attribute\\ScopeOverriddenValue->initAttributeValues('Magento\\\\Catalog...', Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), 0)\n#9 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/AbstractModel.php(328): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Attribute\\ScopeOverriddenValue->getDefaultValues('Magento\\\\Catalog...', Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor))\n#10 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/Product\/Interceptor.php(2091): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\AbstractModel->getAttributeDefaultValue('links_title')\n#11 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-downloadable\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/UsedDefault.php(84): Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor->getAttributeDefaultValue('links_title')\n#12 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-downloadable\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/UsedDefault.php(66): Magento\\Downloadable\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\UsedDefault->titleUsedDefault('links_title')\n#13 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-downloadable\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/Modifier\/Composite.php(81): Magento\\Downloadable\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\UsedDefault->modifyMeta(Array)\n#14 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Ui\/DataProvider\/Product\/Form\/ProductDataProvider.php(73): Magento\\Downloadable\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\Modifier\\Composite->modifyMeta(Array)\n#15 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php(310): Magento\\Catalog\\Ui\\DataProvider\\Product\\Form\\ProductDataProvider->getMeta()\n#16 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php(216): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('product_form', Array, false)\n#17 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)\n#18 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php(97): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Data\\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor))\n#19 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/GeneratorPool.php(80): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Context), Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\Context))\n#20 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php(344): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Reader\\Context), Object(Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\Context))\n#21 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->generateElements()\n#22 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php(129): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->generateElements()\n#23 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Page\/Builder.php(55): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()\n#24 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php(65): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Page\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()\n#25 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php(254): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->build()\n#26 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php(876): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->build()\n#27 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->getBlock('menu')\n#28 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')\n#29 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')\n#30 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/Edit.php(69): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')\n#31 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/Edit\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit->execute()\n#32 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor->execute()\n#33 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#34 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#35 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#36 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(143): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#37 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#38 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#39 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/Edit\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#40 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\Edit\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#41 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#42 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#43 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#44 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#45 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#46 \/www\/sites\/db\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#47 \/www\/sites\/db\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#48 \/www\/sites\/db\/index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#49 {main}","url":"\/admin\/catalog\/product\/edit\/id\/481\/key\/2561921a92ab41586d7c2cbd563d2d8cad1ca2d7c57d0edbaece838b19fc68c0\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Answer (score 0):

this error basically comes due to DB access issue.

1. Check DB credentials in app/etc/env.php
2. clear var/generation or generated folder
3. clear var/cache

and then try .